# Are these relativistic formulae correct?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity

```
 As we know,
     m′= m/√(1-β²)
   ⇒dm′/dt = mγ³aβ/c
                  = m′γ²aβ/c
                  = m′γ²av/c²..........(1)    (just differentiate with respect to time)
     where a is the acceleration.
     From Newton’s law,
     Force (F) = d(m′v)/dt
             = m′a + v.dm′/dt
             = m′a + m′γ²av²/c²   (From (1))
             = m′a(1+γ²v²/c²)
          F = m′aγ²    [since γ = 1/√(1-v²/c²) ]
        ⇒ m′a = F/γ² ...........(2)
    Substituting (2) in (1),
        dm′/dt = Fv/c²
     ⇒  dm′/dx = F/c²..............(3)   [since v = dx/dt]
    where x is distance travelled.
```

Now, the actual question starts:

Consider a mass **m**  which just starts moving towards a fixed mass **M** due to gravitational attraction. Let initial distance between **m** and **M** be **r**. After time **t**, let distance between them be **r′**. Now consider a small instant **dt**.In this instant of time, let the moving mass move through a distance **dr′**. Let velocity of moving mass be **v**. Thus, new mass of moving mass is **m′= mγ**.
[image]

```
As per equation (3),
     dm′/dr′ = F/c²
     where F is GMm′/(r′)²
   ⇒ dm′/dr′ = GMm′/(r′c)²
   ⇒ (dm′)/m′ = (GM/c²)(dr′/r′²)
   Integrating, we get
       ln(m′/m) = (GM/c²)((1/r′)-(1/r))
                      = GM(r-r′)/rr′c² = f(r′)  [say f(x) = GM(r-x)/xrc²]
      ⇒ m’ = m(e^-f(r))
   Is this true? Or have I done mistake anywhere?
   I don’t think e will come into the picture in relativity. Will mass vary exponentially?
```

Comment: (A) Please, please, *please* use MathJax to typeset your equations properly. What you have posted here is painful to read. (B) You've made an assumption that you haven't told us about (concerning the time derivative of $\beta$), which is always a bad start. Either that or you have neglected your chain rule.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You appear to be asking us to check your calculation. The site policy for such exercises is that your question should *ask about a specific concept of physics* so that other people can benefit from it. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have time to thoroughly look through everything, but I believe the problem is one of **interpretation**. Most people don't use the notation $m=m_0\gamma$, because mass should be something that is independent of one's velocity. While that notation makes $E=mc^2$ and $p=mv$ true at arbitrary velocities, it gives this weird conceptual notion that as things accelerate, they gain arbitrarily high masses. We usually trade this in for the notion that as things accelerate, they gain arbitrarily high **energies**. We instead use $p=mv\gamma$ and $E=m\gamma$ (from now on I will use units where $c=1$ and put them back in the final result).

For your problem, you found a differential equation for $m(v)$ and found that it varied exponentially (I haven't checked your math, but it looks clean, so I'll assume it's right) as $m(v)=m_0e^{f(r')}$. This gives a weird interpretation that as the mass falls to a planet, its mass increases exponentially. However, with our interpretation, it is not mass, but **energy** which does this.

However, let's look a bit closer at your equation. We have

$$f(x)=\frac{GM(r-x)}{xr}=\frac{GM}{x}-\frac{GM}{r}$$

Which is simply the difference in potential energies (per unit mass) at $r$ and $x$. Let us define $x=r-a$ so that we have

$$f(x)=GM\left(\frac{1}{r-a}-\frac{1}{r}\right)=\frac{GMa}{r(r-a)}$$

Now, let's do a santiy check: If we have $f(x)\ll 1$, then we can expand $e^{f(x)}\sim 1+f(x)$ so that the energy change is

$$\Delta E\sim m+\frac{GMm}{x}-\frac{GMm}{r}$$

So that the difference in kinetic energies ($K=E-m$) is simply the difference in potential energies, as usual.

Now we might ask under what conditions $f(x)$ is small. If $f(x)\ll 1$, we have

$$GM\ll\frac{r(r-a)}{a}$$

In order for this to be true, we must have $r-a\ll GM$ or $x\ll GM$. This tells us something very important and physical. The standard energy difference we like only works if we don't fall **too close** to the star/planet/thing. In most cases, the actual size of the thing stops this from happening, and relativistic effects are negligible. However, in some cases, the radius $R$ of the star is on the order of $2GM$ (a radius known as the Schwarzschild radius). When this happens, the star collapses into a black hole, and neither Newtonian mechanics nor special relativity can help us.

In summary, your expressions are most likely correct. However, in the extreme cases where they differ from the classical result, we must also encounter gravitational fields so strong that special relativity isn't good enough to describe them. We need general relativity for this.

The moral of the story: when you get a result that seems ridiculous, check the physical limits of it. In yours, for all cases when it is applicable, it is close to the classical result. The exponential behavior never really poses a problem for us. But the other limits are instructive too. They tell you where your expressions break down and when you need new ones.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The one on mass has a big hole in it.  Einstein wrote on the Michelson Morley experiment which does not have the conditions for an axial Doppler shift only  the transverse Doppler shift which the experiment discovered.  For the mass in a photon the complete Doppler shift both axial and transverse: 
m’/m= e’/e= ω'/ω=[[1-v/c  cos⁡θ ]/[√(1-〖(v/c)〗^2 )]  where cos⁡θ is the cosine of the angle between the direction of the closing velocity of the source to the observer and the direction of the light.

As for other masses we measure mass by the size of its' gravitational charge. If one assumes gravity travels like electro-magnetic forces at the speed of light all mass should have an axial shift as well as a doppler shift.

If some lies this response go to the link for my full paper on the subject: https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ajcpi0c5Be4uiHZxJwOi2uMMnGst

Comment: Most writers on relativity forget the axial Doppler shift.   Over half the writers on optics forget the transverse Doppler shift.  The general case is product of the two shifts = the total shift.   This can precess for along time because at velocities much lower than light the transverse shift is 1.  Things moving at velocities significant compared to on earth generate lots nose by giving energy to standing and other electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Maybe I didn't read carefully enough, but I don't see what this has to do with the question.  Can you explain?